MSBUILD how to trigger a target only from current project?
I have a simple library project (ex: HelloWorld) which I added a target to auto-push its NuGet package to a private GitLab repository, the target is like this:
  <Target Name="PostBuild" AfterTargets="Pack">
      <Exec Command="start /WAIT $(ProjectDir)Scripts\postbuild-pack-push.bat $(Version)" />
  </Target>

The above target worked well whenever I built/rebuilt it, it achieved the desired result of pushing the package. However, I have a NUnit unit test project sitting alongside HelloWorld and whenever I run my unit test, it would rebuild its dependency too which would trigger my target.
How can I conditionally invoke the target, iff, is called from within HelloWorld only? I tried adding a Condition but it is not doing anything at all, such as:
Condition="$(ProjectName) == 'HelloWorld'"


Why is build on your HelloWorld project running pack? Was the project customized to always pack on a build? Can that be unhooked? Pack should be a separate operation from build but running the pack target should run the build target if the files are out of date. There isn't a standard way for a project to 'know' that it is being built as a dependency of another project. That's a reason why the build operation should be 'clean' (i.e. not doing steps that are not part of building).

@JonathanDodds I am fairly new to MSBuild, I don't necessarily need to run pack after build but don't know how to trigger my script after manually triggering pack (right-click Project > Pack). That was the only way I found out how to do it.

Ah, I found out what the problem is. I am using Visual Studio 2022 with MSBuild v17, it has the property GeneratePackageOnBuild which mine was set to true. I had to set it to false.
<GeneratePackageOnBuild>false</GeneratePackageOnBuild>

What I had as my target was correct when using AfterTargets="Pack", though I renamed it to better convey its intention.
<Target Name="PushPackage" AfterTargets="Pack">


The version of MSBuild in VS 2022 is v17.

@JonathanDodds ah right, there are so many msbuild... I thought it was using the one in C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\15.0

Open a "Developer Command Prompt for VS 2022". That shortcut runs a batch file that, among other things, sets the PATH for VS2022 and its tools. In the command prompt, type msbuild --version. Two versions will be reported but both should be a major version of 17. To see which executable is being used, type where msbuild.

It is indeed v17, but interestingly, where msbuild showed nothing.

The where command doesn't behave like that. Is it possible that instead of the "Developer Command Prompt for VS 2022" shortcut, you used the "Developer PowerShell for VS 2022" shortcut? In PowerShell where is an alias for the Where-Object cmdlet which is a completely different tool.
